# Page moving to left when dragging mouse to the right

Tags: html, css

I have a layout and the problem I'm having is if I select over anything, even just clicking and holding the background and drag my mouse right, the whole page moves to the left, except the background.

I've tried everything I can think of and was wondering if anyone knew what it could be? I thought it could be a width problem but I've checked it all out and can't find anything.

Comment: If this is code you wrote, then I would check to make sure the logic for the origin is the same as the screen and then check to see if you are not multiplying by a negative somewhere or having the values reversed in a subtraction.

Comment: Could you post a demo on jsfiddle, or link to the webpage you're having problems with? It's hard for us to check something we can't see.